# C++ LNK 2005 Error "already defined in .obj

Tags: c++, lnk2005

Im getting this LNK 2005 error even though I have crated the game class using the proper header file and cpp file format as far as im aware.

Which after googling the problem for a while seems to be the main reason for this error, can anyone see what is is I messed up?

my game.h file is as follows:

```
#pragma once

class Game
{
public:


//Variables
char grid[9][8] = { { '#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#' },
                    { '#','G',' ','D','#',' ',' ','#' } ,
                    { '#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#' } ,
                    { '#','#','#',' ','#',' ','D','#' } ,
                    { '#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#' } ,
                    { '#',' ','#','#','#','#',' ','#' } ,
                    { '#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#' } ,
                    { '#','#','P','#','#','#','#','#' } ,
                    { '#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#' } };
int width, height;
int pX;
int pY;


char direction;
bool west;
bool north;
bool south;
bool east;
int quit;

Game();
};
```

My game.cpp file is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <String> 
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

using namespace std;

//constructoer
Game::Game()
{
    width = 8, height = 8;
pX = 2;
pY = 7;


west = false;
north = true;
south = false;
east = false;
quit = 0;
}
```

My main is literally just creating an instance of the object at the moment

main:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <String> 
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Game.cpp"
 #include "Game.h"


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Game g;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is your main() routine?

Comment: @theRoadToCodeOverload don't put code in comments, but [edit] your question and put that code _there_.

Comment: @theRoadToCodeOverload A [MCVE] and the verbatim error text please.

Comment: Ive added the main to the post

Comment: `#include "Game.cpp"` seems to be the culprit. That's not how things are done.

Comment: oh your right i was supposed to just include the header, cheers

Comment: Don't include the `Game.cpp` in your main. This is most probably the reason of your error. The file contents is compiled twice and on the linking stage there are two definitions of the same ctor.

Comment: @theRoadToCodeOverload don't put the answer into your question. There is already an answer below. and BTW if nobody gives an appropriate answer you can answer your own question if you found out by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When including `game.cpp`, you actually implement the contructor `Game::Game()` twice, i.e. one time in `game.cpp` (which is a separate translation unit) and one time in `main.cpp` (where you include the constructor implementation code).
Hence, you get a linker error, not a compiler error.

To solve the problem, remove the `#include "game.cpp"`.